# How can I convert a file received as blob in HttpResponse call to an audio file in Salesforce Apex coding?

Tags: salesforce, text-to-speech, apex, watson

I am actually trying to implement text-to-speech conversion in Salesforce by hitting a third-party api. When i send the request through Postman, i get back the proper response in .wav format. However, I'm not being able to handle this reponse programatically in salesforce end, as I am not able to store the response in any audio object.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.
Abhishek.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is supported by IBM's Watson Salesforce SDK, available [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/salesforce-sdk)

The functional tests for Watson's text-to-speech services can be found [here](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/salesforce-sdk/blob/develop/force-app/main/test/IBMTextToSpeechV1FTest.cls) refer to the method

> testSynthesize(String username, String password, String customizationId)

The audio file returned as part of the response could be saved as an attachment in Salesforce by simply creating it from the **IBMWatsonFile** like on this example,

```
IBMWatsonFile resp = textToSpeech.synthesize(options);
Attachment attachment = new Attachment();
attachment.Body = resp.body();
attachment.Name = resp.name();
attachment.ParentId = '<your salesforce parent id>';
insert attachment;
```

This code uses basically the method **getBodyAsBlob()** available from the [HttpResponse](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_restful_http_httpresponse.htm) class

before using this approach, please consider the governor limits enforced by Salesforce on any APEX callout, refer to the **Maximum size of callout request or response** documented [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet.meta/salesforce_app_limits_cheatsheet/salesforce_app_limits_platform_apexgov.htm)

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure of what your trying to do but it would look something like this assuming you built your object correctly

```
ResponseObject result = new ResponseObject();

result = (InnerClasses.ResponseObject)JSON.deserialize(json,  InnerClasses.ResponseObject.class);
```

Comment: Hi Eric.

Thanks a lot for your response.

I am already being able to receive the audio response from the api call in blob/string format. However, I'm not being able to convert the same into a format in which i can store it while processing the reponse in my controller class, or while return it to my visualforce page; as the only way to handle audio, from what i searched, is by using the <audio> tag, which is an HTML property and not something salesforce recognizes.

Comment: I've never seen a wav format in a String, and I am unsure what this looks like or what your doing.  Are you parsing your string into a object?

Comment: I am sending my request in String format, while the reply I get from the server is in wav format. I am trying to hold this object inside salesforce somehow, so that I can later let the user hear it.

And no, currently I'm not parsing the response string into an object. would parsing it help by any means?

I'm unsure that after parsing, what will the resultant file be!

Thanks a lot for bearing with me on this. @EricSSH

Comment: I've never heard of getting a response in a .wav format let alone saving it in salesforce